# How to convert sql row data into string or json format?

Tags: php, json

How can i take the data to transfer it into another php file for some sql query function through json? The idea of this is there will show a table take from my sql table with a button every row for every `task_id`. For now, I want to test by clicking on a button of a random table row, i want to test to get the `task_id` replacing the `hi` text. To show that `task_id` has successfully convert into a format that json accept and print out as json text format.

i tried to echo the `task_id` to check the value but nothing happen, so what i need to do? How can I change the row data into something I can use for json?
With fetch? Or?

```
<?php
            $sql = "SELECT * from task t
            inner join tasktracking tt

            $result = $conn -> query($sql);
            while($result && $row = $result->fetch_object()){

              echo "<tr>

              <td>".$row->status."</td>
              <td>
              <button onclick='startProcess(".$row->task_id.")' type='submit'  name='start' id='start'>start</button>
              <button onclick='endProcess(".$row->task_id.")' type='submit' name='end' id='end'>end</button>
              </td>
              </tr>";
            }

            $conn->close();
        ?>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <p id="demo">hi</p>

        <script>
        function startProcess(){
          <?php
          echo task_id;
          ?>
        var myObj, x;
        myObj = {"name":task_id};
        x = myObj.name;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
      }
        </script>

    </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: For me your question is not clear

Comment: @sfili_81 in short, how can I show the `task_id` on the page when I click on the button. For example, I click on the 1 of the row with task id of `2020`, the page should take the data of that row to function `startProcess` and replace the `hi` text as the task id. How can I do this? Do I still need to fetch the sql data to string, if yes, how?